# plotting muliple plots using par on one page

Tags: r, par

I am trying to use par function in base R to make multiple plots on one page. I am using ggscatter function from library `ggpubr` . I did something like this but it does not work

```
library(ggpubr)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(ggscatter(df, x = "a1", y = "a2", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
               add.params = list(color = "blue")))
plot(ggscatter(df, x = "a1", y = "b1", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
               add.params = list(color = "blue")))
```

This should plot on one page, 2 graphs in the first row. But instead it is being plotted on separate pages. Any idea what might be going wrong here

Answer (score 2):

`par()` doesn't work with ggplot. Use `ggarange()`. Try:

```
p1 <- ggscatter(df, x = "a1", y = "a2", add = "reg.line",
         conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
         add.params = list(color = "blue"))
p2 <- ggscatter(df, x = "a1", y = "b1", add = "reg.line",
         conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
         add.params = list(color = "blue"))

ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Check out this link for more info:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this with grid.arrange and it worked. I think plot should be removed when storing in p1 and p2.